# cURL/PHP opening as logged user fails

Tags: php, curl

I'm opening a page as logged user, and it kind of seems to work, except the website has some sort of a protection system. If I do this normally, I'll get the page I want, but if I do it with cURL, I'll get 'Welcome back user (userid)' and a link to the page I requested. Once I click the link, I'll get where I want to be. Now I tried faking the referer and checking the data that gets sent to the page, there's nothing special there. When I click the link, I simply get redirected to the page I wanted in the first place. My question is why doesn't this code get me there as well:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://www.site.com/sell/index");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.site.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Just before I do this, I perform login procedure and grab the cookie. And I do get to open the page as logged in user, I just can't seem to access it without clicking the ahref.

PS. The same thing would happen if I logged in, open the page I wanted, closed browser and opened it again. So I'm thinking it has to do with referer?

Comment: Does using `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );` help at all?

Comment: @Quixrick nope I get the same result. The site knows I'm logged in, but it appears to know I'm using cURL as well. If It makes a difference, the cookie file has more than one cookie in it.

Comment: Hmm, then I do not know.  Only other thing I can think of is to compare the headers from your browser visit with the cURL visit headers. Sounds like you may have already done that, though.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I did.. Unless there's some tool to specifically break this down? I simply checked all the network request.. And they seemed okay >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookie-jar means it will save your cookie from curl's response. That's why it is not working for you. Instead use cookie-file so that your curl send stored cookie with request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKEFILE, "cookie.txt");
```

Also, use absolute path(`/var/tmp/cookie.txt`) instead of relative path.

Now, Be Happy!

Comment: Thank you! I am happy, however, this didn't solve the issue. The site still somehow knows I'm using curl and forces me to hit the `a href` which essentially reloads the page to get to what I want =)

Comment: @SamFisher Check for the other http headers. May be the browser sends the headers like `x-http-header` or something like that, which generates for ajax calls.

Comment: I'll make sure I do this, is there any better way to check exactly what curl needs or do I dig with browser and try to catch it there?

Comment: Always use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to check what is your curl sending. You can use `firebug` extension with firefox to trace the http calls(with request headers) for your action from browser.

Comment: Gotcha, on it right now, will post a solution if I manage to get one =)

Comment: As it turns out, I was trying to open one of the pages I don't need for this project (to test curl) and it was failing. As soon as I switched to one I do need, it started working. So technically, I still haven't found the solution to the specific problem, however, it's not relevant anymore =)